# Position fixed element go out of the page/ window - how to stop at some point?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hope the image explain well about what is the issue I am having because I don't even know what keyword I should search for. The "Contact me orange box" is an overlay box that using position fixed to put on the bottom and right-hand side. But when re-size the window "heigh" the box will go out of the page (see screenshot #2). Is there a way to make the overlay box stop at some point? using CSS or jquery. Please help ><
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max-height` property to something less than the page height. For example, you could do  `max-height: 80%;`. Put this styling on the element you are changing the height of.